# Django pass user id before form is submitted

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

I am working on a Django-Tenant (Multi-Tenant) application. I am writing the script to create the subdomain. I am trying to get it to where `created_by` is set to the current users id that is logged in. How can I get current user ID to populate the `created_by` field?

**views.py**

```
class CreatePortal(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = CreatePortalForm()
        return render(request, "registration/create_portal.html", {"form": form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = CreatePortalForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            getDomain = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            tenant = Client(schema_name=getDomain, name=getDomain, created_by=**[NEED USER ID HERE]**)
            tenant.save()
            domain = Domain()
            domain.domain = (getDomain + ".example.com:8000")
            domain.tenant = tenant
            domain.is_primary
            domain.save()

            with schema_context(tenant.schema_name):
                instance.save()
                redirect = 'http://' + getDomain + '.example.com:8000'
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
        return render(request, "registraton/create_portal.html", {"form": form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class CreatePortalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ["name"]
```

**models.py**

This is the line that I am working with models.py

```
created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I also get an error if it is not User type and if I do not pass an actual number for id, `Field 'id' expected a number but got datetime.datetime`

I have tried this as well:

```
user = request.user.id
tenant = Client(schema_name=getDomain, name=getDomain, created_by=user)
```

but then get this error:

`Cannot assign "1": "Client.created_by" must be a "User" instance.`

I am not sure how to pass the current logged in Users ID to populate the `created_by` form field. Any and all help is appreciated. I am still learning Django.

Comment: Use `user = request.user` instead of `user = request.user.id` it should work. If not you can use `user_id = request.user.id` `user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)`

Comment: So that did move the process along, but now I get this error when I change that. Field 'id' expected a number but got datetime.datetime. Any ideas on what would cause this?

Comment: `user_id = request.user.id` `user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)` you used this and got that error in this line? There is no chance you get that datetime error with that. Check the line in which you got that error and post the same.

Comment: @IbrahimKhan yes, that is exactly what I have and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: cross check the line in which you are getting that error. You can use print() to cross check. Use print(user_id) in the next line of the variable and print (user). If this prints correctly then the problem is not in there.

Comment: @IbrahimKhan so user_id prints correct (gets correct id) but user gets the correct username, but not the id. Not sure if that would cause this issue or not.

Comment: If the user got printed then it means there is no error in user variable. The error what you are getting is else where, not in user. If you had error in user line the next line wouldn't have printed as python executes code line by line. You can check your database if that is getting created.